# Snowflake Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, substring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this string in Snowflake column:

```
\[
{
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 4617,
"name": "SpecTra",
"type": 0
},
{
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 7455,
"name": "Signal Capital Partners",
"type": 0
}
\]
```

I need to get names in this format regardless of the number of company names:  "SpecTra, Signal Capital Partners". In other words, I need to extract company names and concatenate them.

I have tried this :

```
regexp_replace(col, '"(\[^"\]+)"|.', '\\1|')
```

and
**regexp_substr()** function, but did not get the desired output

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col, '"name":\\s*"([^"]+)"|.', '\\1,'), ',+', ','), ',')
```

**Details**:

- `"name":\s*"([^"]+)"|.` regex matches `"name":`, then zero or more whitespaces, and a `"`, and then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `"` and then matches a `"` char, and replaces with Group 1 and a comma
- The second `regexp_replace` shrinks all commas into a single occurrence of a comma, `,+` matches one or more commas (you may also use a more specific `,{2,}` pattern here instead)
- `trim` removes commas from start and end.

Comment: ah good to see you escaped that `\s`

Comment: Hello Wiktor,

Thank you very much for your solution, it has worked!

But, since I am new here, I don't know how to make your answer as a solution

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, can you also recommend some resources to learn regular expressions (e.g. specifically for Snowflake, python and others), please?

Comment: Wiktor, Can you also explain what these parts do?
1) **[^"]+**
2) **|.**
in the pattern "name":\s*"([^"]+)"|.

Comment: @IlkhomOripov for Snowflake, there are little resources since it uses POSIX regex flavor. For Python, see http://regular-expressions.info. You may also follow [my YT channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFeq5T-LNtqpVrn_rcJ9hFw) (but I have not yet added the very basic regex videos).

Comment: @IlkhomOripov `[^"]` - a negated bracket expression, matches any single char other than a `"`. `+` means "repeat the pattern on the left one or more times". `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces. `|` means "OR". A `.` matches  any char but a line break chars (usually, it may be different in POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

So pushing you text blob into a CTE.

```
with data as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('[{"entryListId": 3279,"id": 4617,"name": "SpecTra","type": 0},{"entryListId": 3279,"id": 7455,"name": "Signal Capital Partners","type": 0}]')
    t(str)
)
```

I cannot help but note it's JSON, so lets [PARSE_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html) that and then [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) it, and here are you "names"

```
select 
    d.*
    ,f.value:name::text as name
from data d
    ,table(flatten(input=>parse_json(d.str))) f
```

giving:

| STR | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| [{"entryListId": 3279,"id": 4617,"name": "SpecTra","type": 0},{"entryListId": 3279,"id": 7455,"name": "Signal Capital Partners","type": 0}] | SpecTra |
| [{"entryListId": 3279,"id": 4617,"name": "SpecTra","type": 0},{"entryListId": 3279,"id": 7455,"name": "Signal Capital Partners","type": 0}] | Signal Capital Partners |

And thus to aggregate, using [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html)

```
select 
    listagg(f.value:name::text, ',') as names
from data d
    ,table(flatten(input=>parse_json(d.str))) f
```

gives:

| NAMES |
| --- |
| SpecTra,Signal Capital Partners |

### Duplicate data:

you can add DISTINCT to the LISTAGG and have only the distinct values kept, but given it is a cost, I did point it out, and you didn't mention duplicate data.

```
with data as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('[
    {
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 4617,
"name": "SpecTra",
"type": 0
},   
{
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 4617,
"name": "SpecTra",
"type": 0
},
{
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 7455,
"name": "Signal Capital Partners",
"type": 0
}]')
    t(str)
)
select 
    listagg(distinct f.value:name::text, ',') as names
from data d
    ,table(flatten(input=>parse_json(d.str))) f;
```

gives:

| NAMES |
| --- |
| SpecTra,Signal Capital Partners |

Where-as that regex solution does not handle this case:

```
with data as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('[
    {
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 4617,
"name": "SpecTra",
"type": 0
},   
{
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 4617,
"name": "SpecTra",
"type": 0
},
{
"entryListId": 3279,
"id": 7455,
"name": "Signal Capital Partners",
"type": 0
}]')
    t(str)
)
select 
    trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(d.str, '"name":\\s*"([^"]+)"|.', '\\1,'), ',+', ','), ',') as regexp_replace
from data d
```

gives:

| REGEXP_REPLACE |
| --- |
| , , , SpecTra, , , , , , SpecTra, , , , , , Signal Capital Partners, , |

Comment: Hello Simeon,

Thank you very much for your answer!

Yes, your reasoning also works, but when I flatten and parse, some rows are being duplicated.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I added the keyword to solve your problem, that is noted in the docs linked to for the solution provide. I also show how the rexexp_replace fails your duplicate data test also.